# How to quit / terminate entire unity game from native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I followed below tutorials to integrate unity with iOS application
 1. https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5
 2. https://www.agnosticdev.com/blog-entry/swift/integrating-unity-and-vuforia-ios-swift-project?page=1

I try to stop unity by following code from iOS

```
func stopUnity() {
        if isUnityRunning {
            isUnityRunning = false
            currentUnityController!.applicationWillResignActive(application!)
        }
    }
```

but when i try to start unity again by following code

```
func startUnity() {
        if !isUnityRunning {
            isUnityRunning = true
            currentUnityController!.applicationDidBecomeActive(application!)               
        }
    }
```

It only resume the unity game. I'd to restart the unity game instead of resuming.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1154825/how-to-quit-unity-game-from-ios-native-app.html) is the thread with the same question.

I wish there are next ways to terminate unity:

1) [Application.Quit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html) - it calls `Exit(0)` so it terminates native app too. But we need to close only Unity and let the app work.

> Quits the player application. Shut the running application down. Quit
>   is ignored in the editor.

2) [Application.Unload](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Unload.html) - this is what we want, depending on description, but i didn't get how to make with it yet.

> Unload the Unity runtime. Similar to quitting but the application
>   process does not exit. This is useful when using Unity as a component
>   in another application. For example, if you use Unity to display some
>   special content but do not want to keep the Unity engine resident in
>   memory when it is not needed.

3) Call `unityController?.applicationWillTerminate(UIApplication.shared)` - didn't work for me. Crashed.
4) Add [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) - didn't try.

There i wrote my ideas about that problem. I know that it's not the real answer, but it's better than nothing and maybe broad somebody to the real nice-work solution :)

Answer (score 0):

When using the "Unity as a Library" Feature to integrate Unity into your native iOS application you won't be able to fully terminate Unity and return to your native App.

As stated in the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-iOS.html) on integrating Unity into native iOS applications you are able to call the method `- (void)unloadApplication;` on the UnityFramework instance to release **most of the memory** it occupies, but not all of it. You will be able to run Unity again after doing so.

```
var isInitialized: Bool {
    ufw?.appController() != nil
}

func unloadUnity() {
    if isInitialized {
        ufw?.unloadApplication()
    }
}
```